# How to remove paragraph breaks in openoffice

Tags: line-breaks, libreoffice, openoffice.org, paragraph, openoffice-writer

I am using openoffice 4 and i have a Paragraph Breaks between two pages and i want to avoid it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quiet simple

[image]

You have to unselect the 3rd and 4th option and select the 2nd one.

Now every time the space is not enough for the paragraph it will automatically move it to the next page.

Hope that will help some one.